# Why doesn't the text look the same like in the Illustrator design?

Tags: html, css

[So this is the screenshot from the Illustrator design where you can see how I want the text to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnrO0.png)

I am building my own chrome extension (very first), the coding is done I just have to do the styling now. I've made design in Illustrator and trying to do it that way. Right now I'm having issues with the text design. Text doesn't look the same on the extension and in Illustrator even tho it's the same font (Futura Md BT) with same size (16px)

[In extension text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy0D5.png)

I used Futura Medium BT in Illustrator and imported that font into my html in style with

> @import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/futura-md-bt');

and used it later in

```
<div class="modal-content">
             <p><span style="font-family:'Futura Md BT', 'sans-serif'; font-size=16px">Prebacite eure u kune i obratno s lakoćom!</span></p>
....and so on
```

Why isn't it the same??

Comment: Things like font-size, font-weight, letter-spacing and other properties all have an effect on how a font looks. It's possible that your browser and illustrator use different default values for one (or more) of those.

Comment: Maybe browser does not have `Futura Md BT` and fallsback to default?